# "Xamarin Android" How can i set the TextCell property of a ListView?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.android

In Xamarin Forms we can set the TextCell property like this right?

```
        <ListView x:Name="WorkersListView" BackgroundColor="#ECEFF1" Margin="2" ItemSelected="WorkersListView_ItemSelected">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding WorkerName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

By writing `ListView.ItemTemplate` and `DataTemplate` we can access the TextCell

But how can i do it on **Xamarin Android**?

because it doesn't have `ListView.ItemTemplate` and `DataTemplate` elements.

This is my current `ListView` in my Xamarin.Android project

```
    <ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/WorkersListView"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:layout_margin="2dp">
</ListView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Working with ListView in Xamarin Forms and Xamarin Android is different

Add an XML that looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:orientation="vertical"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"  
android:layout_height="match_parent">  
<ListView  
    android:id="@+id/listView"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

Then create `ListView` template

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:orientation="horizontal"  
android:layout_width="fill_parent"  
android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
android:minWidth="25px"  
android:minHeight="25px"  
android:paddingBottom="4dp">  
<ImageView  
    android:id="@+id/photoImageView"  
    android:layout_width="60dp"  
    android:layout_height="60dp"  
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"  
    android:padding="5dp" />  
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/nameTextView"  
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photoImageView"  
    android:text="Name"  
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />  
<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/departmentTextView"  
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photoImageView"  
    android:layout_below="@id/nameTextView"  
    android:text="Department"  
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" />  
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Create an adapter class something like:

```
public class MyCustomListAdapter : BaseAdapter<User>  
{  
    List<User> users;  

    public MyCustomListAdapter(List<User> users)  
    {  
        this.users = users;  
    }  

    public override User this[int position]  
    {  
        get  
        {  
            return users[position];  
        }  
    }  

    public override int Count  
    {  
        get  
        {  
             return users.Count;  
        }  
    }  

    public override long GetItemId(int position)  
    {  
        return position;  
    }  

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)  
    {  
        var view = convertView;  

        if(view==null)  
        {  
            view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.userRow, parent, false);  

            var photo = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.photoImageView);  
            var name = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nameTextView);  
            var department = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.departmentTextView);  

            view.Tag = new ViewHolder() { Photo = photo, Name = name, Department = department };  
        }  

        var holder = (ViewHolder)view.Tag;  

        holder.Photo.SetImageDrawable(ImageManager.Get(parent.Context, users[position].ImageUrl));  
        holder.Name.Text = users[position].Name;  
        holder.Department.Text = users[position].Department;  


        return view;  

    } 
}
```

A detailed answer is in the blog:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-custom-listview-in-xamarin-android-app/

Answer (score 0):

`ListView` in Android instance requires an `Adapter` to consume the data contained in row Views.

Add one ListView and one TextView control, to display the list of items and the elements respectively. Use the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
   android:orientation="vertical"  
   android:layout_width="match_parent"  
   android:layout_height="match_parent"  
   android:background="#6BC6ED"  
>  
<TextView  
   android:id="@+id/Name"  
   android:layout_width="match_parent"  
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
   android:textSize="25dp"  
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"  
/>  
<ListView  
   android:id="@+id/demolist"  
   android:layout_width="match_parent"  
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">   
</ListView>  
</LinearLayout>
```

Similar to what we did in Forms , create new model class which contains the binding property in ViewCell.

For example

```
public class Students {  
    public string Name {  
        get;  
        set;  
    }  
    public int Age {  
        get;  
        set;  
    }  
}
```

Next, you need to create Adapter to bind the data to the ListView. Android has in-built base adapter class for Adapter implementations to bind a ListView to a data source. Also, we can get item position, count, and selected item, etc. there. Count method is used to get the number of rows in the list.

GetView method is used to return a View for each row, populated with which element.

GetItemId method is used to return row data properties like row number and value.

```
public class StudentAdapter: BaseAdapter < Students > {  
    public List < Students > sList;  
    private Context sContext;  
    public StudentAdapter(Context context, List < Students > list) {  
        sList = list;  
        sContext = context;  
    }  
    public override Students this[int position] {  
        get {  
            return sList[position];  
        }  
    }  
    public override int Count {  
        get {  
            return sList.Count;  
        }  
    }  
    public override long GetItemId(int position) {  
        return position;  
    }  
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
        View row = convertView;  
        try {  
            if (row == null) {  
                row = LayoutInflater.From(sContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.Main, null, false);  
            }  
            TextView txtName = row.FindViewById < TextView > (Resource.Id.Name);  
            txtName.Text = sList[position].Name;  
        } catch (Exception ex) {  
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);  
        } finally {}  
        return row;  
    }  
}
```

Next, open your activity file and write the below code to create a list of items to display a ListView and show the selected items from the list.

```
private ListView studentlistView;  
private List < Students > mlist;  
StudentAdapter adapter;  
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle) {  
    base.OnCreate(bundle);  
    // Set our view from the "main" layout resource  
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);  
    List < Students > objstud = new List < Students > ();  
    objstud.Add(new Students {  
        Name = "Jack", Age = 26  
    });  
    objstud.Add(new Students {  
        Name = "Mary", Age = 26  
    });  
    studentlistView = FindViewById < ListView > (Resource.Id.demolist);  
    mlist = new List < Students > ();  
    mlist = objstud;  
    adapter = new StudentAdapter(this, mlist);  
    studentlistView.Adapter = adapter;  
    studentlistView.ItemClick += StudentlistView_ItemClick;  
}
```

To handle the selected items, write the below code.

```
private void StudentlistView_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e) {  
    var select = mlist[e.Position].Name;  
    Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(this, select, Android.Widget.ToastLength.Long).Show();  
}
```

For more details you can check [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-use-list-view-and-adapter-in-xamarin-android-application/) .